# Stop ajax request using javascript/jquery - JSF

Tags: javascript, ajax, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have following code

```
<rich:calendar enableManualInput="true" value="#{myBean.myDate}" 
    oninputblur="validateDate(this);">

    <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{myController.method()}" render="myPanel"></a4j:ajax>

    <a4j:ajax event="inputchange" listener="#{myController.method()}" render="myPanel"/>

</rich:calendar>
```

As you see **`oninputblur`** I am calling a javascript function. I donot want to send ajax request to server if `validateDate` return false. How can I handle this?

Comment: You're basically ignoring the return value of the function.

Comment: How can I utilize the return value, of `validateDate`, so that I can stop ajax request ?

Comment: Ajax call is received, at server end, even if `validateDate()` is not completed. So return false from js function isn't helpful here. Is there anyother solution to stop ajax ? Thanks

Comment: @BalusC the a4j:ajax doesn't listen to the same event, and in this example the request is sent before the validation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use @onbeforesubmit (see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/a4j/ajax.html#onbeforesubmit)) on a4j:ajax. If it returns `false` the ajax request will be cancelled.

In your example the request fires before the validation (since the `change` event fires before `blur` - although that looks to be browser dependent)

Comment: I remove the `oninputblur` attribute from `rich:calendar` and put `onbeforesubmit=validateDate(this);` in both `a4j:ajax`. When it `return false;` it send the ajax call to server anyway.

Comment: You really need to understand how functions work. onbeforesubmit has to return false, and you're not returning anything. `validateDate(this)` translates into `validateDate(this); return undefined;`

Comment: Sorry to barge in. Instead of `onbeforesubmit=validateDate(this);`, put `onbeforesubmit="return validateDate(this);"`. This way it is actually returning the returned flag from `validateDate`.